# Python Divide a list by all elements of a second list

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists,

```
a = [6,9,8]

b = [2,3,4]
```

Can I divide the first list by corresponding element in the second list?

To get an output like `c = [3,3,2]` because `[6/2=3, 9/3=3, 8/4=2]`.

Something like `c = [a(0)/b(0),a(1)/b(1),a(2)/b(2)]`?

Comment: `[item1/item2 for item1, item2 in zip(a, b)]`?

Comment: Perfect! That was fast fourtheye! Thanks a ton.

Comment: You might want to look into `numpy`, if you cast your lists to `numpy` arrays, all you have to do is `a / b`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up elements of 2 or more lists:

```
c = [a_elem // b_elem for a_elem, b_elem in zip(a, b)]
```

I used `//` to do integer division, as you are expecting integer output.

On Python 2 this won't make any difference as both operands are integers and you presumably did not use `from __future__ import division`, but on Python 3 or when using the *future* import using the `/` operator will result in a `float` result instead.

Demo on Python 3 showing the difference:

```
>>> a = [6, 9, 8]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4]
>>> [a_elem // b_elem for a_elem, b_elem in zip(a, b)]
[3, 3, 2]
>>> [a_elem / b_elem for a_elem, b_elem in zip(a, b)]
[3.0, 3.0, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use enumerate dividing elements at common indexes:

```
a = [6,9,8]

b = [2,3,4]

print([ele // b[ind] for ind,ele in enumerate(a)])
[3,3,2]
```

If you had a lot of data numpy might be a good option:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([6,9,8])

b = np.array([2,3,4])

print(a//b)

[3 3 2]
```

If you happen to have one list longer than the other you could use itertools.izip_longest with a fillvalue of 1 so we keep the element from the longer lst:

```
a = [6,9,8,4]

b = [2,3,4]

from itertools import izip_longest

print([x//y for x,y in izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=1)])
[3, 3, 2, 4]
```